# Antlr Input Matching both parsing rule and a Lexer

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar for parsing arithmetic expressions.

When I am trying to add support for Unary minus (-) I am facing the following issue:

The input is matching only when I give a space between, eg - 10.

If the input is -10 it matches the Word since its a valid Lexer too.

How do I change my grammar so that I can use unary operator without space.

```
grammar Arithmetic;

parse
 : expression EOF
 ;

expression
 : op=SUBTRACT exp=expression
 | left=expression op= EXPONENT right=expression
 | left=expression op= DIVIDE right=expression
 | left=expression op= MULTIPLY right=expression
 | left=expression op= MODULUS right=expression
 | left=expression op= ADD right=expression
 | left=expression op= SUBTRACT right=expression
 | INTEGER
 | WORD
 ;

ADD          : '+';
SUBTRACT     : '-' ;
MULTIPLY     : '*' ;
DIVIDE       : '/' ;
MODULUS      : '%' ;
EXPONENT     : '^' ;
INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
WORD         : (ALPHANUMERIC | '_' | '-' | '.' | SQ | DQ)+;
WS           : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
ALPHANUMERIC : [a-zA-Z0-9];
SQ           : '\''.*? '\'';
DQ           : '"'.*? '"';
```

Comment: How are you testing this grammar? It fails for input `- 1` because you do not have a lexer rule for whitespace. It parses fine `-1` ***without a space***.

Comment: It works for -1 but that is recognised as a word but I would like that to match the rule `op=SUBTRACT exp=expression`

Comment: Added WS, so - 1 should work

Comment: What are words supposed to represent? Both numbers and variable names? Shouldn't those be separate things? Either way, why do you want to allow `-` in words? To allow variable names with dashes (like `this-is-one-variable`)? If so, how do you want to distinguish a variable name with dashes in it from a subtraction? Like, how would you decide whether `x-y` is supposed to be one variable named `x-y` or two variables being subtracted from each other?

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend that you look at the arithmetic grammar in grammars-v4, [specifically the ordering and grouping](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3b26af5ec5cfc28779e609b3f20fc7e6454c51d4/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4#L46-L52) in `expression`, which is used to implement operator precedence. Your grammar will yield atypical parse trees.

Comment: @sepp2k yes initial thought was to allow variables with -. But as you said in that case its hard to predict whats the intent

Comment: But i have some implementations handle both, not sure how

Answer (score 0):

> If the input is -10 it matches the Word since its a valid Lexer too.
>
> How do I change my grammar so that I can use unary operator without space.

That is impossible. You'll need to change the lexer rule that matches a `Word`. ANTLR's lexer works in a very predictable way (regardless of what the parser is trying to match):

1. find a lexer rule that consumes the most characters
2. if 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

So, that would make it clear that `-10` will always become a `Word` token. No way around it.

> So in that case I will need to remove `-` from my `WORD` definition?

Yes, at the very least. But the `WORD` rule is still fishy: it also matches `SQ` and `DQ`, making those tokens to be never created (check point 2 above). Ans as it stands, a `WORD` would also match `..........______________`, which seems odd.

Comment: So in that case I will need to remove `-` from my work definition?

Comment: Okay I think I will change my definition of WORD here so that it has to start with alphanumeric

Comment: Even if it starts with an alphanumeric, you’ll have trouble with the following words: `2-1`, `a-b`, …

Comment: An identifier with a hyphen is very strange (if you also use the hyphen as a minus operator). That would need to change, because it is not possible to determine during tokenization if a hyphen belongs to a `WORD` or is a minus operator.

Comment: Yes agreed to that